# problem upgrading openssl on ubuntu servers

Tags: linux, openssl, heartbleed

I'm running Ubuntu x86_64, and want to upgrade to OpenSSL `1.0.1.f`.

```
wget <openssl latest>
tar -xzvf openssl.tar.gz
cd <openssl dir>
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
```

In the console output, I get the following error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `apt-get`?? Off-topic for this site, anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that this topic is not security related, but related to Ubuntu administration, you should really use a package manager, like `apt-get` or `aptitude`.